# How to replace odd number of single quote with two single quote

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to add escape character `"'"`(single quote) in string in java but only when there is odd number of occurrence using Regular Expression

For Ex:

1. if string is like `"string's property"` then output should be `"string''s property"`
2. if string is like `"string''s property"` then output should be `"string''s property"`

Comment: What happens with 3 quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
\'(\')?
```

**Demo (replacing with `'`)**

http://regexr.com?38eeh

Comment: Ehm. So is the question about JavaScript?

Comment: @KeyurArdeshana Glad to know it worked for you. For the benefit of the community, marking an answer as correct (the 'tick' next to it), it's a great way of letting others know too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (even count).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "a''''''b";
    str = str.replaceAll("[^']'('')*[^']", "###");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Then try this one (odd count).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "a'''''''b";
    str = str.replaceAll("[^']'('')*[^']", "###");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Hm. Indeed. But why?! Oh OK nvm.

Comment: Thanks but not working properly as i tried with string like `keyur'''''s what's up?`  and result is `keyur''s what''s up?`. where i expected as `keyur''''''s what''s up?`. look at the count of single quotes after keyur

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// input that will be replaced
String replace = "string's property";
// input that won't be replaced
String noReplace = "string''s property";
// String representation of the Pattern for both inputs
//                 |no single quote before...
//                 |    |single quote 
//                 |    | |... no single quote after
String pattern = "(?<!')'(?!')";
// Will replace found text with main group twice --> found
System.out.println(replace.replaceAll(pattern, "$0$0"));
// Will replace found text with main group twice --> not found, no replacement
System.out.println(noReplace.replaceAll(pattern, "$0$0"));
```

Output:

```
string''s property
string''s property
```